# Passing Messages from iFrame Across all Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed

I have an embed-able iframe that will be used on 3rd party sites. It has several forms to fill out, and at the end must inform the parent page that it is done.

In other words, **the iframe needs to pass a message to it's parent when a button is clicked.**

After wading through oceans of "No, cross-domain policy is a jerk" stuff, I found [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage), part of the HTML5 Draft Specification.

Basically, you place the following JavaScript in your page to capture a message from the iframe:

```
window.addEventListener('message', goToThing, false);

function goToThing(event) {
    //check the origin, to make sure it comes from a trusted source.
    if(event.origin !== 'http://localhost')
        return;

    //the event.data should be the id, a number.
    //if it is, got to the page, using the id.
    if(!isNaN(event.data))
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost/somepage/' + event.data;
}
```

Then in the iframe, have some JavaScript that sends a message to the parent:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    parent.postMessage(someId, '*');
});
```

Awesome, right? Only problem is it doesn't seem to work in any version of IE. So, my question is this: Given that I need to pass a message *from* an iframe to it's parent (both of which I control), **is there a method I can use that will work across any (>IE6) browser?**

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main work-around I've seen used involves setting a hash value on the parent window and detecting the hash value in the parent, parsing the hash value to obtain the data and do whatever you want.  Here's one example of doing that: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage/.  There are more options via Google like this one: http://easyxdm.net/wp/.

Comment: That looks promising; trying this now.

Comment: After reading up on your link, I ended up with a hybrid solution. If postMessage is supported the browser uses it, otherwise it uses the older url-hash style and polling. To support the back button, I added an extra step that sets window.location.href = '#!', clearing the hash value from the url immediately after it's found.

Answer (score 6):

In IE you should use

```
attachEvent("onmessage", postMessageListener, false);
```

instead of

```
addEventListener("message", postMessageListener, false);
```

Answer (score -4):

This is way simpler than that.

You say you control both the parent and the content of the frame you can set up two way
communication in javascript.

All you need is

```
yourframename.document.getElementById('idofsomethinginttheframe')
```

And then from inside the frame address anything outside it with

```
parent.document
```

Comment: Eeeh...I don't like dealing with DOM manipulation for data passing if I can get away with it. I went with the URL hash approach instead.

Comment: He's talking about "3rd party sites", so direct access is not possible because of SOP.

Comment: @webjunkie I know SOP very well, but you did not fully read the post. "Then in the iframe, have some JavaScript that sends a message to the parent" + the code. you can only do that if you have the ability to edit the source in the iframe. Therefore whatever the OP may have said in the intro, is not consistent with the ability to change code in the framed content. If you have that ability it is not a 3rd Party Site being framed. If you downvoted because of this then I ask you to please correct it.

Comment: @T9b Ability to control or change code in the parent frame is not the same as parent and child frame having the same origin.

Comment: @webjunkie That is not what I said. I was talking about the ability to change the code in the child, which is incidentally also what the OP has said they have done in the post, but then you didn't read it properly or my reply. Clearly it's not worth arguing with someone who doesn't read the questions properly.

Comment: @T9b The 3rd party site is the parent site. Go read it properly yourself. There is SOP in effect here, that's why he even started asking with PostMessage.