# iFrame / Javascript doesn't update

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I'm actually learning Javascript and especially Iframes.

So I made a form which is checked by `request.php` and then sent to my iframe via `target : framename.php` with a function wich update my iframe.

The problem is that my frame doesn't update, and I have no console message.

I show you the code :

index.php

```
<form id = "welcome" action = "request.php" target = "hello" method="post">
    <label for = "welcomeMsg"> Message : </label>
    <input id = "welcomeMsg" name = "welcomeMsg" type = "text"/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "send" />
</form>



<iframe src = "hello.php" id = "hello" name = "hello"></iframe>

<script>

function sayMsg(welcomeMsg){

    var frame  = document.getElementById('hello').contentDocument;
    frame.innerHTML = welcomeMsg;
}

</script>
```

request.php

```
<script>
window.top.window.sayMsg("<?php echo $_POST['welcomeMsg']; ?>");
</script>
```

hello.php (iframe)

```
<p id = "mess"> Hello </p>
```

You may think 'Why are you using a html page as an iframe because an id would work', it is because I will customise this hello.php.

Comment: Iframes are html not js, Iframes are usually a bad idea, there are much better approaches in most cases

Comment: Please describe your problem, 'doesnt work' is not detailed enough

Comment: You know you can fetch arbitrary html from a php script and put it into a div from your javascript **without** an iframe, right? It actually makes almost everything easier.

Comment: Maybe you have to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479246/passing-messages-from-iframe-across-all-browsers

Comment: Is it just me? I am not seeing a question here. What do you want to do? And what **specific** problem are you having?

Comment: My iframe doesn't update when I send something with the form.

Comment: This is the most peculiar setup I have seen in a long time :) Why do you want to inject a <script> from request.php, when you could add the message from the form / index.php itself?? I guess you want to store the message, like in some chat-system, but the one does nor prevent the other. Change the form to an ajax-call, and update in the background.

Comment: Well, It is because I need to upload an image and add text on it without reloading the page...

Comment: AJAX is your friend! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started for pure javascript examples, or use a library like jQuery which make it very quick to code by `$.ajax({ .. })`

Comment: Yes, AJAX is nice but I can't upload an photo and show it without reloading the entire page.