# Creating a frame redirect causes Chrome to throw X-Frame-Options error

Tags: http, redirect, discourse

`Refused to display 'http://sotaexchange.cloudapp.net/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

I redirect my domain sotaexchange.com to a Discourse forum but get the above error.  If I switch it to an HTTP redirect there is no problem.  I *assume* the problem is because my redirected to domain has the same text as the original domain and looks like trickery - what can I do to prevent this?

**Edit**

I am opening a bounty to get a better answer.  For more info, I am currently using Windows Azure to host the discourse site and redirecting from a few other domains that I own.  I don't want to use an HTTP redirect, I would like to use the Frame redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to mask the url of the forum. Why don't you use the cname feature? See [cname on azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript#Definition_of_an_origin) policy requires that the document or script doing the accessing (the parent) have the same protocol , port, and domain as the resource it's accessing (the child).

If I understand correctly, you have a frame in a page on the domain `sotaexchange.com`, and it's trying to display content from the domain `sotaexchange.cloudapp.net`. This violates the same origin policy, and many browsers will reject it. A regular HTTP redirect should always be ok.

Comment: Your answer is basically just restating what I said in the problem.  I am looking for answers that provide the ability to get around this issue or offers some insight that leads to a solution.

Comment: Sorry if the first answer is not what you're looking for. This browser behavior is not an "issue", but a security feature, so it's difficult to get around it. It would be helpful if you could post some of the redirect code you're using, but without seeing it, I might suggest [message passing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage). Some discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479246/passing-messages-from-iframe-across-all-browsers

Comment: As I posted in my question I am using a frame redirect so there is no code to post.  Perhaps if you posted something along the lines of - 'This violates the same origin policy because of x and y and avoid this to allow it to work' then this might be a suitable answer.