# How can I call a javascript function from within iframe?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, web, same-origin-policy

I've had a read about and I'm aware of the fact the same-origin policy would prevent the DOM of an iframe accessing the parent window's DOM and vice versa if on different domains.

However, I do, in this case, have at least some control of the parent DOM too (it is still on a different domain). I'm developing a site to sit in the iframe but will also be asking users to add some javascript to the head of their page.

Given that, is there anyway I can expose a javascript function in the parent with that included javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7479286/3556874

Comment: i solved it with easyXDM.js cross-domain messaging

Comment: You just saved the day @NaeemShaikh. I'll look into `window.postMessage` a bit more, it's exactly what I'm after. Thanks for your reply john, I'll look at the HTML5 approach first and then if all else fails have a read into easyXDM. I'd rather reduce the need for 3rd party components (I'm assuming it is) until necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm delighted to say, HTML5 appears to tackle this problem head on with `window.postMessage`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

According to the link Naeem posted in the comments, there may be some compatibility issues with certain browsers, but that can be overcome.